# Best Practices for Securing an authoritative DNS

Tags: linux, dns

I am trying to implement the best practices for securing the Linux `bind` DNS.

I have never gone this in-depth with securing authoritative DNS before. What do you recommend?

Comment: Have you looked up the many, many hardening guides: https://www.google.com/search?q=bind+dns+hardening

Comment: As the question is too open-ended, the best advice is to follow a hardening guide. A proper guide will provide full coverage of the various things you need to consider.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too open-ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cloud service provider's public DNS, such as Amazon's [AWS Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/). Google GCP and Microsoft Azure also offer similar services, this will be much more cost-effective, performant and available compared to running your own service.

If you must run your own service, best practice is to implement a hidden/stealth master design with DNSSEC:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8499/ > see 'Hidden Master'.
A reasonable how-to using ISC BIND is here:
https://www.c0ffee.net/blog/dns-hidden-master

It is also possible to combine both an on-prem (in the DC) and CSP service for the ultimate resiliency, i.e. if one or more clouds fail. You can also invest in vendor solutions to manage all of this from a single pane of glass, such as [DNS Cloud](https://www.efficientip.com/simplify-management-of-dns-services-with-dns-cloud-extension-to-azure-dns-zones/) from EfficientIP

In terms of hardening the service, follow best-practices for public servers exposed to the internet, such as using Fail2Ban / [CrowdSec](https://www.crowdsec.net/), reducing attack surface with firewalling, remove all unused packages etc., ensure automation in place for security and other important updates, ensure you have automated monitoring and alerts enabled. Then, for BIND you should ensure you are only answering queries for your zones, do not allow recursion, do not allow zone transfers. More info here:
https://kb.isc.org/docs/bind-best-practices-authoritative > 6) Prepare for abuse of any external-facing servers